# psql: could not translate host name "woken.c6dvrobkl4yw.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

psql: could not translate host name "woken.c6dvrobkl4yw.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

I am getting this error when i am trying to connect to aws via psql command.

how to resolve this issue any idea?

Comment: Where are you trying to connect from? How long has it been launched?

Comment: The RDS is launched 4-5 months back and it was working fine until yesterday.I am trying to connect it from ec2 instance

Comment: Does rebooting the EC2 instance help at all. The error you're seeing is a DNS resolution issue so would be good to check if you can resolve anything or if its just this specific resource

Comment: This specific domain only i am not able to resolve .

Comment: FYI when I ping it, it resolves to an IP. Must be an issue on your side.

Answer (score 0):

check if your instance has internet access & nameserver is properly configured it should not be pointing to 127.0.0.1